# How to resolve "property [propName] does not exist on [object]"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I am using TypeScript with React and when I run my tsc/jest test it is returning the errors for all of my components similar to this:

```
Property 'prop name' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

Folder/Component Structure:

```
– ExampleComponent
  - component.tsx
  - index.ts 
  - styles.css 
  - styles.css.d.ts
```

Component.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'designlibrary';
import styles from './styles.css';

export interface TypeExports {
  title: string;
  text: string;
}

export const Blurb: React.FunctionComponent = (props: TypeExports) => (
  <div className={styles.blurb}>
    <Text color='primary' size='h3' type='h3'>
      {props.title}
    </Text>
    <Text color='primary' size='p1' type='p'>
      {props.text}
    </Text>
  </div>
);
```

index.ts

```
export { Blurb } from './component';
```

styles.css.d.ts

```
interface CssExports {
  blurb: string;
}
declare var cssExports: CssExports;
export = cssExports;
```

I was getting similar errors for exporting classes and since I added the above into the the `.style.css.d.ts` file, it resolved all of the css related typescript errors.

An example of the error that is still returned with the component above is:

```
Property 'text' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

EDIT:

After Nicholas help, this is the structure of the working component:

```
export interface TypeExports {
  title: string;
  text: string;
}

export const Blurb: React.FunctionComponent<TypeExports> = (props) => 
  <div className={styles.blurb}>
    <Text color='primary' size='h3' type='h3'>
      {props.title}
    </Text>
    <Text color='primary' size='p1' type='p'>
      {props.text}
    </Text>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React.FunctionComponent is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html). You can tell it what your props are, and it will adjust its types accordingly. Since you havn't told it what the props are though, it thinks there are no props. Do this instead:

```
// I'd probably name this interface "BlurbProps", but that's up to you
export interface TypeExports {
  title: string;
  text: string;
}

export const Blurb: React.FunctionComponent<TypeExports> = (props) => {
  // etc
}
```

I left out the type on `(props)`, since it can now be inferred. You're welcome to re-iterate the type if you like and keep it as `(props: TypeExports)`, but the important thing is to add `<TypeExports>` after `React.FunctionComponent`

Comment: Thank you for the response! 
I have tried the above and on the last line of the component after the closing parenthesis it shows error saying 'Declaration or statement expected.'

Comment: I'd have to see the latest code to know what the syntax error is caused by. Note however that in my example i used curly brackets for the function body while in your example you did parentheses and an implicit return. So if you copied mine verbatim, that might be the problem (in which case, either add a return, or switch it back to parentheses for the implicit return)

Comment: You're right! I just saw that I had a parenthesis instead of the curly bracket! 

Now it* looks like it's removed a bunch of the errors and replaced them with this: 

`Type '(props: PropsWithChildren<TypeExports>) => void' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<TypeExports>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null'.`

Comment: if you still have `props: TypeExports`, remove the `: TypeExports`. Looks like i was wrong about you being able to keep it. (because the actual type would be `props: PropsWithChildren<TypeExports>`)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you, but I think it is close. This is what I have for my component: 
`export const Blurb: React.FunctionComponent<TypeExports> = (props) => { . }`

Comment: When I load the page in browser this is the error I am getting with your above code: 
"Blurb(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null."

Comment: @AsafAviv sorry? I don't understand

Comment: I've updated my question with the latest syntax/structure

Comment: You're using the curly brackets, as in my example. That's fine, but then you need a return statement. For arrow functions with exactly one statement, javascript allows you to leave off the curly brackets and the `return` will be implicit. But if you keep the curly brackets, then you need to be explicit.